# Two identical R value finding z value from two transaction

Tags: transactions, signature, hash, ecdsa

[tx1](https://blockchain.info/tx/9312ccafb8aa624afe7fb7b4201a0ccc2a14ca2b8b8a3253093b975a6a85a280)

from the trans1 i got

Input Scripts

```
30450220262e481b6d8905b5adba67aff05eb8261501b0a9434c0b7f043d00cf8d23c91b022100bf82c0d212f30d3a0599e9b879516d762eaf5688ab83787cf470e99af5a6917101       
046578188abe5aaf9f3d1809d972e87307493dfefa3a5b6c94c870e8f58743179678f059c6402d9806ccce5d0672dc171d962fe392f8ef77cc9827c3eb633966b4
```

R = 262e481b6d8905b5adba67aff05eb8261501b0a9434c0b7f043d00cf8d23c91b

S2 = bf82c0d212f30d3a0599e9b879516d762eaf5688ab83787cf470e99af5a69171

**tx1 raw trans**

```
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
```

**calculating z2**

replace the input with the corresponding output script

```
01000000012eb64643254262722e33e72cb2ad67fecb6ae2fd812d2f2bff217458715e11a0000000001976a91409a4cb092dc30da1354369fc78f482365ce2767a88acffffffff02a0252600000000001976a914cf3aaf67c964d5c239f4cf2d9c2d2a7257d85b5d88aca0252600000000001976a91409a4cb092dc30da1354369fc78f482365ce2767a88ac0000000001000000
```

then do sha256(sha256(modified transaction))

Z2 = e2b8acb01c0ea6a2a1273fc9dbbe3cdd58c68afb54e240e1f51abcc652468204

[tx2](https://blockchain.info/tx/b4e7193c972ababd82b5feefe1af96b33bf062d2b959f44816a532e05940d032)

**from tx2**

Input Scripts

```
30450220262e481b6d8905b5adba67aff05eb8261501b0a9434c0b7f043d00cf8d23c91b022100d45c9ef85bb65a2a5bb3cf862124188adfe5fb8d430bc4b0d1222b1704d10d1901      
046578188abe5aaf9f3d1809d972e87307493dfefa3a5b6c94c870e8f58743179678f059c6402d9806ccce5d0672dc171d962fe392f8ef77cc9827c3eb633966b4
```

S1 = d45c9ef85bb65a2a5bb3cf862124188adfe5fb8d430bc4b0d1222b1704d10d19

**tx2 raw trans**

```
010000000180a2856a5a973b0953328a8b2bca142acc0c1a20b4b77ffe4a62aab8afcc1293010000008b4830450220262e481b6d8905b5adba67aff05eb8261501b0a9434c0b7f043d00cf8d23c91b022100d45c9ef85bb65a2a5bb3cf862124188adfe5fb8d430bc4b0d1222b1704d10d190141046578188abe5aaf9f3d1809d972e87307493dfefa3a5b6c94c870e8f58743179678f059c6402d9806ccce5d0672dc171d962fe392f8ef77cc9827c3eb633966b4ffffffff01a0252600000000001976a914cf3aaf67c964d5c239f4cf2d9c2d2a7257d85b5d88ac00000000
```

**calculating z1**

replace the input with the corresponding output script

```
010000000180a2856a5a973b0953328a8b2bca142acc0c1a20b4b77ffe4a62aab8afcc1293010000001976a914cf3aaf67c964d5c239f4cf2d9c2d2a7257d85b5d88acffffffff01a0252600000000001976a914cf3aaf67c964d5c239f4cf2d9c2d2a7257d85b5d88ac0000000001000000
```

then do sha256(sha256(modified transaction))

I got Z1 = f62dab861eb451dad7cc74fa9f754e4d233b5fb80b1327fd623f5617e1f46d21

but the correct z1 value is

z1 = 66042ab1a1befe137de5328ff1d4b263604824fe33c739d3a80565afdd94b34d

what wrong in the calculation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **calculating z1**
>
> replace the input with the corresponding output script

This is the step where you made a small mistake.

The UTXO that's being spent is from [txid 9312ccafb8aa624afe7fb7b4201a0ccc2a14ca2b8b8a3253093b975a6a85a280](https://blockchain.info/tx/9312ccafb8aa624afe7fb7b4201a0ccc2a14ca2b8b8a3253093b975a6a85a280) which contains two txouts. When you did the script replacement, you chose txout #0 (with a hash160 of cf3aaf67c964d5c239f4cf2d9c2d2a7257d85b5d), but the tx being signed is spending txout #1 (with a hash160 of 09a4cb092dc30da1354369fc78f482365ce2767a).

Doing the replacement with the correct txout script results in this, which hashes to the z1 value you were expecting:

```
010000000180a2856a5a973b0953328a8b2bca142acc0c1a20b4b77ffe4a62aab8afcc1293010000001976a91409a4cb092dc30da1354369fc78f482365ce2767a88acffffffff01a0252600000000001976a914cf3aaf67c964d5c239f4cf2d9c2d2a7257d85b5d88ac0000000001000000
```

Comment: Christopher Gurnee thank you now i get correct output

Comment: @Prabur If this has completely answered your question, please consider Accepting it (and of course the same goes for any other answers). More info on Accepting answers can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/